# Strange array behaviour with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a two dimensional array in controller:

```
var MainController = function($scope) {
    $scope.board = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
                    [5, 6, 7, 8],
                    [9, 10, 11, 12],
                    [13, 14, 15, 16]];
};
```

And I want to display it as table:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="line in board">
        <td ng-repeat="cell in line">
            {{ cell }}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

All work fine with this code, but if I change the data in the board to make two identical cells in the line (inner array) - this line disappear.  So if I change controller to:

```
    $scope.board = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
                    [5, 6, 7, 7],
                    [9, 10, 11, 12],
                    [13, 14, 15, 16]];
```

the second line disappear.

Why and how can I fix it?

Comment: could you post a plunkr or a fiddle version of the code so we can play around with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sees the identical values as duplicates. Modify your view by adding `track by` syntax as follows

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="line in board track by $index">
        <td ng-repeat="cell in line track by $index">
            {{ cell }}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This

> will cause the items to be keyed by their position in the array
>   instead of their value

See [Duplicate Key in Repeater](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes)

Comment: Seems like a bug in angular being institutionalized. It is not a duplicate key - keys are the array indices.

Comment: Not a bug; this is exactly what `track by` is intended to solve.